# Is it possible to put one E0 voice signal directly into a STM1 frame

Tags: telephony

I've been going through STM1 frame structure recently.

Is it possible to put a single E0(64kbps) voice channel directly into a stm1 frame or should it be put sequentially into a E1 and then to an E2 and so on and finally an E4 into a STM1 frame.

I've done enough of googling but still couldn’t get it cleared.